# .htaccess rewrite to redirect to subdirectory with variable

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I'm trying to edit my .htaccess file when it contains a certain url link to look in a subdirectory

so I need this

```
/?mdocs-file=811
```

to redirect to this

```
/v2/?mdocs-file=811
```

One other thing the file number which is "811" in this example is a variable so how do I make it so its a place holder for changing numbers?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((?!v2).*=)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ v2/?%1%2 [L]
```